# Why the allocator type as a template parameter rather than a ctor's parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, standards, allocator

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct allocatorA: public std::allocator<T> {};

template<class T>
struct allocatorB: public std::allocator<T> {};

int main() 
{    
    std::vector<int, allocatorA<int>> c1;
    std::vector<int, allocatorB<int>> c2;

    c1 = c2; // error! counter-intuitive and gratuitous
}
```

However, if we move the allocator type from template parameter to the constructor's parameter, then the code is more intuitive and more expressive as follows:

step 1: define a generic interface for all allocator classes

```
template<class T>
struct IAllocator
{
    virtual ~IAllocator();      
    // other stuff like std::allocator
};

template<class T>
struct MyAllocator : IAllocator {};
```

step 2: define a container class

```
template<class T>
struct MyVector
{
    template<class allocatorT>
    MyVector(allocatorT alloc = MyAllocator<T>())
    : _alloc(new allocatorT(alloc)) 
    // can be optimized here. This is just a poc
    {}

    // other stuff like std::vector

    T* _internal_buf;
    IAllocator* _internal_alloc;
};
```

step 3: define two different allocator classes

```
template<class T>
struct allocatorX: public MyAllocator<T> {};

template<class T>
struct allocatorY: public MyAllocator<T> {};
```

step 4: use `MyVector` happily!

```
int main() 
{    
    MyVector<int> c3(allocatorX<int>());
    MyVector<int> c4(allocatorY<int>());

    c3 = c4; // OK
}
```

Comment: For many containers the allocator isn't responsible just for allocating the elements. Often, a **rebind** of the allocator to direct a different *type* is required (such as allocating nodes in an RB tree for a map, pages for hash tables, etc). I invite you to try factoring that in to a constructor-arg scheme. Its doable, but hideous.

Comment: virtual -> dynamic dispatch -> run-time overhead.

Comment: Why not all iterators derive from std::iterator? Why not all containers derive from a common thing like std::collection? Because C++ is not Java. C++ has powerful templates, with both polymorphism and zero runtime cost.

Comment: Haha, `_alloc(new allocT(alloc))`. That's good stuff. Now your vector can be on the stack and two heaps!

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption in step 1, where you you require all allocators to be derived from the same type is not necessarily usable in all situations.